# Update immutable object without breaking immutability in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, immutability

If an object is Immutable in Javascript, how do I update its values and how do I get the updated value from its variable.

For example:

```js
const todo = {
  text: 'Eat',
  completed: false
};

// To update todo completion to true
const updatedTodo = Object.assign({}, todo, { completed: true });
```

I can't reassign the new `updatedTodo` to `Todo` because I used `const`. If I change `const` to `let` and reassign it, doesn't that break immutability.  I'm probably missing something.

Comment: _"If an object is Immutable in Javascript, how do I update its values and how do I get the updated value from its variable"_ You don't. That's part of what makes it immutable.

Answer (score 0):

`todo` is immutable but its properties aren't. You can change them either via `Object.assign(todo, { completed: true})` (note how there's no empty object at the start, that way `todo` is actually modified), or you can simply set it via `todo.completed = true`.